# Not able to consume messages using kafka-console-consumer.sh

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I have set up an AWS cluster of 3 nodes.I have modified the /etc/hosts file for the nodes which looks something like this

`172.31.9.2 kafka1
172.31.9.2 zookeeper1
172.31.19.230 kafka2
172.31.19.230 zookeeper2
172.31.35.20 kafka3
172.31.35.20 zookeeper3`

when I run the command from one of the nodes

> bin/kafka-console-consumer.sh --bootstrap-server kafka1:9092 --topic first_topic --from-beginning

it works but when I replace the hostname by ip and run it with the below command

> bin/kafka-console-consumer.sh --bootstrap-server 172.31.9.2:9092 --topic first_topic --from-beginning

it does not work. Do I need to change certain configs?

Comment: Where are you running `kafka-console-consumer` from? The nodes, or somewhere else (e.g. your local machine)?

Comment: I am running from one of the nodes where I have hosted kafka

Answer (score 1):

When specifying the hostname in the 'listeners' configuration item in server.properties, use 0.0.0.0 as the host to make kafka accept connections more permissively. There's some documentation to that effect [here](https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#brokerconfigs) I believe the recommended access method is to keep it locked down as you have it now and access brokers by host name, though.